# MEF 2 GetExports() fails with strange error

Tags: c#, mef

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Registration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MefTest
{
    public interface ITest {}

    public class TestObj : ITest {}

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RegistrationBuilder rb = new RegistrationBuilder();

            //Register the class
            rb.ForType<TestObj>().Export();

            var container = new CompositionContainer(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), rb));

            //get the type of the first part (there is only 1), which is TestObj
            Type t = ReflectionModelServices.GetPartType(container.Catalog.Parts.First()).Value;

            Type t2 = typeof(TestObj);

            if (t.Equals(t2)) //They look the same in the debugger??
            {
                //This works
                var test1 = container.GetExports(t2, null, null).FirstOrDefault().Value;

                //Fails with ArgumentException: MethodInfo must be a runtime MethodInfo object.
                var test2 = container.GetExports(t, null, null).First().Value;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I created the above example to demonstrate the problem that I'm having. The _container.GetExports(t2...) where I hard coded the type works.
But when I look up the type from the _container.Catalog.Parts with a linq query, it fails with a mysterious error message.

Can anyone give me a hint, what I'm doing wrong?.

**Edit**: Simplified the test case

**Edit**:
I found the problem, t and t2 are not exactly the same.
t2 is a System.RuntimeType and t is a System.Reflection.Context.Custom.CustomType

I have no solution yet, but something to research further.

Comment: whats the "mysterious" error message?

Comment: ArgumentException was unhandled (MethodInfo must be a runtime MethodInfo object.)

Comment: what line throws that?

Comment: var test2 = container.GetExports(t, null, null).First().Value;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I solved my own problem:

So in .Net 4.5 there is this new feature called CustomReflectionContext, which Ian Griffiths explains here: [.NET 4.5 CustomReflectionContext: what is it useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507270/net-4-5-customreflectioncontext-what-is-it-useful-for)

In short, RegistrationBuilder is a CustomReflectionContext, so the types that MEF is using are "virtualized" types (System.Reflection.Context.Custom.CustomType) and not the ones that are actually defined in the assembly (System.RuntimeType).
Which causes a problem when it comes to the instantiation of the object.

The solution is to use the UnderlyingSystemType property of the Type object. Which points from the type lives in the ReflectionContext to the real one that was defined in the assembly.

So my code above has to look like this to work properly:

```
var test2 = container.GetExports(t.UnderlyingSystemType, null, null).First().Value;
```